# Sending a value from textfield in SwiftUI to remain once the textfield is clear

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am fairly new to Swift and SwiftUI programming and I have come up again a weird issue.

My goal is to read the variable in the text field and have the variable print as a comment once the user has clicked return (oncommit).

I tried to use a single $comment variable but that updates both the Text result as soon as the user is typing in the text field.

My goal is for the user to be able to type in the text field and the variable just appears in the section under the text field: ("Your Comment is:"")

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow sorry if I added too much code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private var numberofImages = 7
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @State private var comment:String = ""
    @State private var userComment:String = ""
    @State private var showComment:Bool = false
    
    func previous() {
        withAnimation {
        currentIndex = currentIndex > 0 ? currentIndex - 1 : numberofImages - 1
        }
    }
    
    func next() {
        withAnimation{
        currentIndex = currentIndex < numberofImages ? currentIndex + 1 : 0
        }
    }
    
    var controls: some View {
        HStack{
            Button {
                previous()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            }
            Spacer().frame(width:100)
            Button {
               next()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
            }
            .accentColor(.primary)
            
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                ScrollView{
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
            ForEach(1..<numberofImages) {
                num in Image("\(num)")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                    .tag(num)
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9))
        .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height / 3)
        .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
            next()
        })
                controls
                    .padding()
                Text("Product Description").font(.largeTitle).bold()
                
                    Text("""
                    Incredibly light and boasting a speedy performance, get your work done anywhere with the MacBook Air (2020). From video-editing to gaming, the Apple M1 chip lets you take on the biggest tasks without draining your battery.
                    It's 3.5x faster than the previous generation, with eight-cores of power providing an incredible performance. And for whisper-quiet operation, the improved thermal efficiency means it doesn't even need a fan.
                    With the Retina Display screen, everything from blockbuster movies to everyday browsing is a visual joy.
                    True Tone technology automatically adjust the display to your environment - so web pages and emails look as natural as if they were printed.
                    """) .padding() //.frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
                //Comment Text Field will need to go here. So it can be included within the scroll view.
                    TextField("", text: $comment, onEditingChanged: {_ in
                        self.showComment = true
                    }, onCommit: {
                        if self.showComment {
                            self.comment = self.userComment
                        }
                    })
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    
                    Text("Your Comment is: \(self.userComment)")
                    // Rating Section will need to go her as well. SystemName:Star.circle.fill or unfill.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace:

```
self.comment = self.userComment
```

with:

```
self.userComment = self.comment
```

You are showing `userComment` in the Text (`Text("Your Comment is: \(self.userComment)")`), while `comment` is the `TextField`'s current text.